# Azure continuous deployment clear dlls

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, tfs

After updating to the latest version of devexpress all the dll files got their name changed from SomeName.13.2.dll to SomeName.14.1.dll. 
I included the latest in the project but when I deploy, the old are still in the bin folder on Azure.
Is there any way I can modify the build definition so it deletes the unnecessary files?
I tried setting Allow Upgrade to false but it did not help.

Comment: I deleted the old dlls manually from server explorer and all is fine now but will still like to know if this can be automated.